# Selenium chromedriver fails from cron job?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use `cron` to start a session of `chromedriver`

I keep getting this error:

> (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
>     (The process started from chrome location /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=71.0.3578.98,platform=Linux 4.15.0-45-generic x86_64)

It works fine if I run from Pycharms

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver", options=options)
```

I have tried a bunch of things, for example:

```
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

But it just doesn't work from `cron`.

Comment: JFYI a contributed below the CW answer has made a comment. This may be more to you than to me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author, to move it to the answer space)*.

Found the problem.

Basically `cron` doesn't know where to display. So we need to tell it in crontab where to display i.e.

```
export DISPLAY=:0;
```

You need to find the `:0` part using `grep`.

Don't forget the `;`.

Comment: In my case, I started connecting remotely and this error popped since then. I didn't imagine the display number could change. Check if `env | grep 'DISPLAY'` gives you `:1` and change your display number.